# Testflight false iOS version detection

Tags: ios, testflight

We're using testflight to test our iOS builds. We tested on a couple of devices but on one of the iphones (4s, iOS 8.1) the app is not on compatible app list, but on incompatible apps. when we try to install anyway, we get an error on testflight browser: `your device is running iOS 7.0.4 but this build requires iOS 7.1`
did anyone else encounter this problem? it seems to be a bug on testflight. how to workaround this problem, so testers we send the app through testflight doesn't encounter this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reconnect the device.  See here:  http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/1306270-%22this-build-requires-ios-7-0%22-what-do-i-do-